# ansible cannot use variable

Tags: ansible, roles

I created a role and with a variables file named `defaults/main.yml` with following content:

```
level1:
  level2_1:
    level3_1: "value_3_1"
  level2_2:
    level3_2: "value_3_2"
    level3_3: "{{ level1.level2_1.level3_1 }} {{  level1.level2_2.level3_2  }}"
```

When I try running inside a task file it throws `An unhandled exception occurred while templating`.

I have tried changing the `level3_3` line without adding parrents but also throws an error.

The only way I found to work is if I remove indentation from `level3_3` which will not make it part of the structure.

How can I compose a variable similar to `level3_3` inside the structure without throwing an error?

Comment: It's not possible by design. See [Can't reference a dict key inside the same dict #50280](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280). Create compounds outside the dictionary.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Sorry to find about this. It would have been a better naming and structuring by far

Comment: Well, it's less problematic then it seems, I think. I've put an example into the answer. There are also other solutions suggested in #50280. If you have any other use-case feel free to post it. I'm sure there will be a moderate solution available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible by design. See [Can't reference a dict key inside the same dict #50280](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280). Either create compounds outside the dictionary or put the repeating values into a variables. For example

```yaml
val_A: value_3_1
val_B: value_3_2

level1:
  level2_1:
    level3_1: "{{ val_A }}"
  level2_2:
    level3_2: "{{ val_B }}"
    level3_3: "{{ val_A }} {{ val_B }}"
```

I'd prefer this structure. It's simpler and less error-prone.