# In ansible how do I concatenate a already defined variable in a settings file yaml and an extra-var?

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, concatenation

I created a settings file called `settings.yaml` that looks like this:

```
cust_int: 'ens224'
cust_sub_int: '{{ cust_int }}.{{ cust }}
```

- cust_int, is the already defined variable above
- cust, Is a variable provided with `--extra-var`

here is the playbook:

```
- name: Include vars
  include_vars:
      file: ../../../settings.yaml
      name: settings

- debug: msg="{{ settings.cust_sub_int }}"
```

When trying to concatenate this way I get unclear error that the playbook "did not find the expected key".

My question is, how can I combine these two variables in my settings file? I dont want to have to use `set_fact` in all my playbooks.

Comment: Please show us the playbook in which you are trying to concatenate these values.

Comment: You cannot because the `include_vars` with the parameter `name` will create you a dictionary with properties. And you cannot reference another property of the same dictionary: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280#issuecomment-450901757

Answer (score 1):

See [ansible cannot use variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388638/ansible-cannot-use-variable/63390630#63390630) to learn details why this is not working. The solution is rather simple. Split the settings into common variables and the dictionary. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat settings-common.yaml
_cust_int: 'ens224'
```

```yaml
shell> cat settings.yaml
cust_int: '{{ _cust_int }}'
cust_sub_int: '{{ _cust_int }}.{{ cust }}'
```

Include both files

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: settings-common.yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: settings.yaml
        name: settings
```

Running the play with extra var *`cust=foo`* gives the expected result

```yaml
  settings:
    cust_int: ens224
    cust_sub_int: ens224.foo
```

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
├── settings-common.yaml
└── settings.yaml

0 directories, 5 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: settings-common.yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: settings.yaml
        name: settings

    - debug:
        var: settings
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ settings.cust_sub_int }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e cust=foo

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  settings:
    cust_int: ens224
    cust_sub_int: ens224.foo

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: ens224.foo

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```